# How do you manage LVL unlicensed response?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm currently implementing LVL on my app and I thought about making a little joke that'd render the app unusable or very unconfortable to use when the app is unlicensed. What do you think about that? DO you think is better to just notify the user and close the app (or take the user to the market)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly advise against making it insulting in any way. I implemented LVL in my application with a simple popup and then redirect to to the Android Market. Unfortunately, there were a LOT of false positives (where users who had purchased the application could still not validate). I mentioned in the popup to contact me if it was a mistake, so I was able to help or refund these users, but I got quite a few negative reviews from it even implemented like that. I imagine the exchanges would have been significantly less friendly if my LVL dialog had been rude. (As a side note, I actually ended up removing LVL due to the false positives and because it was getting pirated anyways--both of which I probably could have improved with more code, but I decided it just wasn't worth it)

Comment: Yeah, you're not the first one telling me he abandoned LVL at the end. I guess it's not really worth the effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that making app unusable is not good idea. If I see such an application, then I think that this application unusable at all, either pirated or licensed, and of course I will not buy it (even if I was notified about not licensed app).

Comment: So, what would be a "correct" use of LVL in your oppinion? Just notifying?

Comment: A thought (that I'm trying) is to have the behavior of the paid version revert to the free version features if the LVL fails.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the LVL in my app during months. Because of false positives, I added some logging into the market licensing libraries, at many steps during the licensing process. And I added a "Send report" button to my "Unable to verify license" dialog, to allow easily sending the log to me by email. Side note: when the license could not be verified, my app simply refused to work.

In the end, it worked quite well (< 5% false positives, almost no bad comments), most problems seemed to come from network problems, but also from people with some custom/exotic ROMs and system hacks. This later problem, which affected legitimate users, led me to deactivate the LVL protection. Actually, there are other strategic reasons too (you know, piracy is also some kind of free advertising...).

Anyway, I'm thinking about putting the LVL protection back. And I may add some kind of sophisticated "Manual activation" workaround for false positives, based on automatic retrieval of order numbers from Google Checkout on my own server, and requiring the user to enter his order number to unlock the app.